# Icelandic language process in R

Tags: arrays, r, string, encoding, utf-8

I'm a student doing some research with R.
I tried to put some icelandic language in array but R automatically convert this to english.

```
artist = vector()
artist[1] = "CHVRCHES"
artist[2] = "Fall-Out-Boy"
artist[3] = "Green-day"
artist[4] = "Sigur-Rós"
```

When I try to call 4th item of 'artist' array, console's output is like

```
Sigur-Ros
```

not

```
Sigur-Rós
```

Thus, I looked out for some question that might help me with encoding mess like

```
artist[4] = stri_conv("Sigur-Rós","","UTF-8")
```

or

```
artist[4] = iconv("Sigur-Rós","","UTF-8")
```

But console showed the same output.

I'm doing this on Rstudio and my R version is 3.1.2 . Workspace is Windows 8.1, 64-bit.

Can anyone know how to deal with this encoding problem? I really need some help.

Comment: Can you add `sessionInfo()` output to your question? For all it's worth, I could not reproduce this problem on my Linux machine. I don't have any Windows 8.1 available, but I might check on Windows 7 later on.

Comment: Checked on Windows 7 machine. String is displayed as expected. I guess it is locale problem, but there's not much anybody can do without `sessionInfo()` output.

Comment: @MirosławZalewski Well, my sessionInfo() output isR version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Korean_Korea.949  LC_CTYPE=Korean_Korea.949    LC_MONETARY=Korean_Korea.949
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                 LC_TIME=Korean_Korea.949    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.1.2